# Oracle SQL: Multiple lines of output per student

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on a SQL statement for a vendor who's product's import feature calls for separate lines of data per student who are involved in special programs. For example:

```
Student ID    Program Name
12345         Special Education
12345         Title 1
12345         Limited English
67891         Special Education
67891         Gifted and Talented
```

I'm not sure how to write the query statement to give me a separate line of data per student for each program they are involved with, instead of a single line with multiple columns. Can anyone get me pointed in the right direction?

My table structure is as follows

Table:  Students
Relevant Columns:

```
    student_number     FLOAT(126) 
    last_name          VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
    first_name         VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
    iep                NUMBER(10) 
    ellstatus          NUMBER(10) 
    gifted             NUMBER(10) 
    title1             NUMBER(10) 

    (plus hundreds of other non-relevant fields)
```

Thank you.

Comment: did you write a select statement?  your question cannot be answered as written - you must at least specify the original table structure for some help - and you will likely get downvoted or closed if you do not show what you have already attempted.

Comment: I'm sorry but why is `student_number` a float? Are you going to have 3.40282E+38F different students?

Comment: Yeah...  good question.  I didn't design the product I'm working with, just using it.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the table structures, I am guessing your have the student info and the program info in separate tables. So you will do something like this:

```
SELECT s.StudentId, p.ProgramName
FROM students s
INNER JOIN programs p
   ON s.studentid = p.studentid
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified - the student table contains both the student id number, and several separate fields (one for each program) to indicate the student's participation in these programs.

Comment: Please edit/update the question, and show us the table definition(s).

Comment: per request, I have included the table structure.

Comment: @Brian what field is the program in?

Comment: Each of the iep, ellstatus, gifted, and title1 fields are all individual programs, so there is no one field that I'm looking at - I have to consider them all.  Whenever I find a value in one of those fields, I need to write a line of data.  So if a students has a '1' in the iep field, but the others are null, there should only be one line of data.  However, if both the iep and ellstatus field have values, I need to write two lines of data for that singular student.

Comment: @Brian the table structure shows the vales as numbers but the data sample shows varchar. Do you have a table to join to get the varchar value?

Comment: No, there is no table to get the varchar as in my sample.  Each of these program fields will have one of several numeric values.  For example, the iep field may have '1' which means one kind of an iep, a '2', which means another type of iep, or a '99' which means not applicable.  For the purposes of this query, I'm not so concerned with the value in the field, so long as it's not a '99'.  Either value of '1' or '2' indicates that the student has an iep of some kind, which is all I care about.  So the query should write "Special Education" any time it encounters a '1' or '2' in the iep field.

Comment: I think Pablo's example will probably do the trick for me, however, THANK YOU for taking the time to work through this with me.  I do appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have the program information in each of the different columns (iep, ellstatus, gifted, title1). If this is the case; then it is not a normalized database, and it will probably give you some trouble later on.

As I don't know exactly how you map the number values of the iep, title1, gifted, ellstatus to the programs, I'll give you a way to select the numbers, giving one row for each student/field relationship. You can add the formatting to the query to display the program names as you expect.

This is using the union operator. This operator unites the result sets of two different queries. If you don't use **union all**, then the repeated rows will be displayed once only. I added **all** because I guess the numbers might be repeated.

```
select student_id, program from (
  select student_id, iep program from students where iep is not null
   union all
  select student_id, title1 program from students where title1 is not null
   union all
  select student_id, gifted program from students where gifted is not null
   union all
  select student_id, ellstatus program from students where ellstatus is not null
);
```

To read more about the union operator, you can go here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries004.htm

Comment: If you want help doing the formatting, then you will need to post how you map the numeric values in the fields to the program names.

Comment: Pablo, I think this will probably do the trick for me.  Thank you so much for providing this example!